# Where is the Radio Group Object

Tags: android, eclipse

I cant find any Radio Group Object in eclipse's graphical layout view. Its not there in form widget. I m using Eclipse Version: Helios Service Release 2 for android development.

Answer (score 2):

Under the latest Android tools (ADT 21.1), the `RadioGroup` can be found under the **Form Widgets** header.

[image]